# Ulock FL Studio 21

Tags: software-installation

This may have been asked before but I'm having trouble unlocking FL Studio 21. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, installed with Snapd and registered with my Imageline account. I go through the normal process through FL studio and it says license installed and when it reopens it's still in trial mode.
I tried running regedit and installing the regkey that way but nothing seems to work. I'm at a loss and it may be something really stupid that I'm missing but has anyone had any luck getting the regkey file to install and unlock?

---

Not sure why the down votes. I have a legal copy registered in my name with my account I just can't get it to unlock. I can see the license in the registry in regedit but for some reason my fl studio program isn't unlocking the full version.  It's still in trial mode.